# Webpack plugin, when build a virtual module?

Tags: webpack

I'm making a webpack plugin which extract content from javascript files, and then inject a new module generated from that content.

I extract the content this way:

```
var content = [];
compiler.parser.plugin("call " + this.functionName, function (expr) {
    //example of extraction:
    content.push(this.evaluateExpression(expr.arguments[0]).string);
});
```

And inject the new module this way:

```
var needRebuild = true, source = '';
var buildPromise = Promise.resolve();
var listModule = new Module(); //TODO refactor and extend Module
listModule.identifier = listModule.readableIdentifier = function () {
    return listModuleName;
};
listModule.needRebuild = function () {
    return needRebuild;
};
listModule.build = function (options, compilation, resolver, fs, callback) {
    var that = this;
    //Here is my problem. For now I try to delay the build with a promise.
    buildPromise.then(function () {
        //example of source generation
        source = "module.exports=" + JSON.stringify(content, null, '  ') + ';';
        needRebuild = false;
        callback();
    });
};
listModule.source = function () {
    if (this.useSourceMap) {
        return new OriginalSource(source, this.identifier());
    } else {
        return new RawSource(source);
    }
};
listModule.size = function () {
    return source.length || -1;
};


compiler.plugin("normal-module-factory", function (normalModuleFactory) {
    normalModuleFactory.plugin("resolver", function (next) {
        return function (data, callback) {
            if (data.request === listModuleName) {
                return callback(null, listModule);
            }
            return next(data, callback);
        }
    });
});
```

So my issue is that the virtual plugin is built too soon, before I parsed all the content.

I try to delay the build with a promise, and resolve the promise in, for example, `compiler.plugin("compilation",`. But that doesn't seem to work. I can't find the appropriate place to resolve the promise / do the build.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if it will solve your problem - and you've probably moved on since posting this question - but I built a similar plugin. https://github.com/rmarscher/virtual-module-webpack-plugin